# python creating a list from lines in a file

Tags: python

I need to create a list of strings for each line in a file.

Example:

```
This is my file.
These are examples.
```

would create: ['This', 'is', 'my', 'file']
              ['These', 'are', 'examples']

I need to do this because I am trying to translate a file into a pig latin file.

Comment: What have you tried?  Even if your attempt is just reading lines from the file, that's a great place to start.

Comment: I literally just have  inputFile= open(fileName, 'r') and I really don't have an idea where to go from there.

Comment: Well, any answer is going to involve iterating over lines in a file.  Why not do a search to figure out how to get the lines?  After you've gotten the lines, then you can start working on how to transform them into the lists you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split each line in the file along the space character and retrieve it as a list.

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
li = [line.split() for line in f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
res = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         res.append(line.split())
```

OR:

```
map(str.split, open(filename, 'r'))
```

If you need to get rid of dots:

```
res = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         res.append(line.strip('.').split())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the readLines

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = [line.split(' ') for line in f.readlines()]
```